# No line outputted in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, osx-mavericks

When I run the following code, instead of outputting text, it just displays a new line.

```
f = open('log.txt', 'a+')

nick = raw_input('Choose a nickname: ')
print('Your nickname is now ' + nick)


f.write(nick + ' has joined the room.\n')
print f.read()
```

When I look in log.txt, it has the correct text in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a file as `"a+"`, you're specifically pointing the computer at the last line of the file and telling it "Start reading from here." That's why you're able to append to it, since it's not going to write over anything starting from the end.

That's also why calling `f.read()` won't find anything. If you have the text:

```
File: foo.txt
Body:
Nick has joined the room.
Dave has joined the room.
Sally has joined the room.
```

But when you open the file, you open it after that last period, all you'll read is:

```
''
```

To solve this, use `seek`.

```
f = open('foo.txt','a+') # better to use a context manager!
f.write("bar.\nspam.\neggs.")
f.read()
>> ''
f.seek(0) # moves the pointer to the beginning of the file
f.read()
>> bar.
>> spam.
>> eggs.
```

Comment: How do I avoid this, and open the file to append and read from the top? Or will I have to open it, write to it, then close and reopen it again to read it?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you write to a file like this, it leaves the pointer at the end of the file so when you do f.read() it will only show the empty space at the end of the file (after "nick + ' has joined the room.\n'").

Add the line: `f.seek(0)` before your print statement. (This will put the pointer back to the very start. The 0 can be replaced by whatever position you want the pointer to start at)